# Синхронный ajax-запрос в ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Нужно написать функцию, которая проверяет на сервере доступ пользователя. Что-то типа:

```
CheckAccess : function (name)
{
    Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'index.php',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    r: 'Ajax/CheckAccess',
                    name: name
                },
                failure: function(){
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({title:'Ошибка',msg: 'Не удалось выполнить запрос',buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK}); return;  
                },
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.responseText=='1')
                        return true;
                    else return false;   
                }
                callback: function(options, success, response){
                    if(response.responseText=='1')
                        return true;
                    else return false;   
                }
            });
}
```

Но проблема в том, что она возвращает значение еще ДО получения ответа сервера. Работа пользователя все равно будет "заморожена" проверкой. Посему считаю синхронность оправданной. Может я не прав. Принимаются любые варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

хм..вот так вот, наверное:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url : '/index.html',
async   : false,
failure : function(){alert('Error');},
success : function(response){
    alert('ok');
```

честно говоря, не уверен, но вообще простым гуглением можно найти вот это: 
http://code.google.com/p/ext-basex/wiki/FAQ
и даже вот это: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233071/ext-js-synchronous-ajax-request

Comment: @DreamChild, Оказывается только в ExtJS 4 реализовали параметр async. Посему вызывать следует Ext4.Ajax.request... НО! В голову пришло иное решение (последовательность): сообщение об ожидании, ждать 3 секунды ответа, получен (можно раньше) - работаем дальше, не получен - сообщение "превышено время ожидания". Это вроде должно быть лучше?

Comment: вы удивитесь, но я не знаю, что такое ExtJS - просто аналогичным образом асинхронность выключается в ajax-запросах с помощью JQuery. Ну а гугл мою догадку подтвердил